# summarize top sheet using cell reference from other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to summarize a top sheet by using the cell references from the individual sheets. The code I have written is as below :

```
Sub consolidate()
' pulldata Macro

    Dim asmsheets As Integer 'iterator for looping thru' individual sheets
    Dim Topsheetrow As Integer 'select rows for pulling data from asm sheets
    Dim Topsheetcol As Integer 'select columns for pulling data from asm sheets
    Dim formulastring As String 'string for formula to pull data from the relevant cells from the asm sheets
    Dim chooseasm As Integer
    Dim asmsheetcol As Integer
    
    Regions = Array("Homanjit", "Alok", "Jitendra", "Vijay", "Karthikeyan") 'array to store asm individual sheets
    
    Worksheets("Topsheet").Activate
    
    For Topsheetrow = 3 To 7
        For Topsheetcol = 2 To 7
            Cells(Topsheetrow, Topsheetcol).Select
                For chooseasm = 0 To 4
                    Asm = Regions(chooseasm)
                    Select Case Topsheetcol
                        Case Is = 2
                             asmsheetcol = 4
                        Case Is = 3
                             asmsheetcol = 13
                        Case Is = 4
                             asmsheetcol = 14
                        Case Is = 5
                             asmsheetcol = 15
                        Case Is = 6
                             asmsheetcol = 24
                        Case Is = 7
                             asmsheetcol = 25
                   End Select
                
                   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " " = " & " '" & Asm & "'!r" & 33 - Topsheetrow & "c" & asmsheetcol - Topsheetcol"
                
                Next chooseasm
            Next Topsheetcol
    Next Topsheetrow
End Sub
```

unfortunately while the code runs without an error, the Topsheet returns all values as FALSE.

Am I missing something in the code?

Many thanks in anticipation

Comment: That `FormulaR1C1` string looks wrong - what is the output in the cell?

Comment: I am pretty sure there something missing in the formula string but am unable to pin it down. The result returned is "FALSE" in the Topsheet

Comment: = " " = "  seems a bit strange. = "=" & ...
I think in the moment you check if  a blank equals the result and this will result in false
Write the correct formula in a cell, select it  and in the immediate window :
`?ActiveCell.formulaR1C1`  if you really want to use R1C1 Type and look at the formulastring that will help you

Comment: Your code only populates `Cells(Topsheetrow, Topsheetcol)` (but multiple times) - aren't the values for different values of `Asm` supposed to go into different cells?

Comment: @RedHare - thanks for the revert...I did exactly that and this is the code it was returning : =+Homanjit!R33C2  , but when I tried to convert it to a VBA formula string as : formulastring = "= "+" & asm & "!" & "R" & (33-topsheetrow) & ":C" & (asmsheetcol-topsheetcol)", it is giving an error....does the asm variable also need to be wrapped in double quotes?

Comment: @TimWilliams - I noticed that and corrected the algo. Now the logic flow is working fine, except that I am still not able to fix the formula string to reference the relevant sheets from each individual sheet. Any help appreciate here.

Comment: Your code populates `Cells(Topsheetrow, Topsheetcol)` five times for each run of the inner loop.  Unless you can explain how that needs to be changed it's difficult to fix.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for being in my corner. Is there a way I can share the revised code as I dont seem to be able to do it while inside the comments box.

Comment: You can edit your question and add the revised code.